# Looping TEXTJOIN using vba in excel for multiple outputs

Tags: excel, textjoin

I am venturing into excel VBA the first time and wanted to run a series of codes to textjoin several columns. How do I set it to loop for selected row +1

What I would like to achieve is essentially

for each row,

column Q output = textjoin columns R : Y, separated by commas "," , and ignoring empty cells

column AG output = textjoin columns AH : AL, separated by commas "," , and ignoring empty cells

column AN output = textjoin columns AO : AS, separated by commas "," , and ignoring empty cells

until last filled row

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post the code that you developed so far and also some exemplary data set.

Comment: actually i dont have a clue where to start as it's my first attempt